# Estoy trabajando con DATATABLE, como puedo guardar la pagina actual en la que estoy, para luego al volver mostrar la misma pagina?

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables

Saludos, soy nuevo en la comunidad! Espero correcciones en caso de estar mal formulada la pregunta!

Tengo en un Dashboard datos desde una DB que estan paginados. Estoy utilizando DataTable.
Al precionar sobre uno de los productos voy hacia los detalles del mismo.
Cuando quiero volver a la view anterior, con boton VOLVER, quisiera ir a la pagina de la tabla en la que estaba. 
Si se comprendio, alguno podria darme una mano?

Muchas gracias!!

Esta es la View donde tengo la tabla

```
<link href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap- 
datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-
datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/parsley/src/parsley.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/DataTables-1.9.4/css/data-
table." rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">

tr{cursor:pointer;}
.stats-info > h4, .stats-info > p{
    color: black !important;
}

</style>
<div id="content" class="content">

<?php if($data['rol'] <= 3){ ?> 


<div class="panel panel-inverse">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-heading-btn">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-success" data-click="panel-reload"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-warning" data-click="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>               
        </div>
        <h4 class="panel-title">Formularios Mantenimiento</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4"><button id="nueva" type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-l-20 m-t-20">Nueva Solicitud</button></div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 ui-sortable" style='background-color:#FFBABA;'>
                        <div class="widget widget-stats" >
                            <div class="stats-info">
                                <h4>Pendientes</h4>
                                <p><?=$estados['pendientes']?></p>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 ui-sortable" style='background-color:#FFE8AD;'>
                        <div class="widget widget-stats" >
                            <div class="stats-info">
                                <h4>En Proceso</h4>
                                <p><?=$estados['proceso']?></p> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 ui-sortable" style='background-color:#94DDCF;'>
                        <div class="widget widget-stats" >
                            <div class="stats-info">
                                <h4>Cerrados</h4>
                                <p><?=$estados['cerrado']?></p> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nº</th>
                            <th>Fecha Registro</th>
                            <th>Origen</th>
                            <th>Cierre</th>
                            <th>Fecha Cierre</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <?php if($data['rol'] == 1): ?>
                            <th>Eliminar</th>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        foreach ($solicitudes as $solicitud) 
                        {
                            $fechaR = new DateTime($solicitud->fecha);

                            if (isset($solicitud->fecha_cierre)) 
                            {
                                $fechaC = new DateTime($solicitud->fecha_cierre);
                                $fechaC = date_format($fechaC,'d-m-Y');
                            }
                            else
                                $fechaC = '';

                            $estado = $solicitud->estado;
                            if($estado == 0) $estado = "<td style='background-color:#FFBABA;'>Pendiente</td>";
                            elseif ($estado == 1) $estado = "<td style='background-color:#FFE8AD;'>En Proceso</td>";
                            else $estado = "<td style='background-color:#94DDCF;'>Cerrado</td>";

                            echo "<tr id='".$solicitud->id_solicitud."'>";
                            echo "<td>".$solicitud->id_solicitud."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".date_format($fechaR,'d-m-Y')."</td>";                               
                            echo "<td>".$solicitud->origen."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$solicitud->nombre.", ".$solicitud->apellido."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$fechaC."</td>";                                
                            echo $estado;
                            if($data['rol'] == 1)
                                if($solicitud->estado == 0)
                                    echo "<td class='action'>"."<a class='btn btn-danger btn-icon btn-circle btn-sm btn-delete'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a>"."</td>";
                                else
                                    echo "<td></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    ?>                          
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
<?php } ?>  
</div>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" id="modal_delete">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eliminar orden</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ¿Está seguro que desea eliminar la orden?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form method="POST" action="<?=base_url()?>insumos/eliminar">
            <input type="hidden" name="solicitud" id="solicitud">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<?php $this->load->view('view_scripts') ?>


<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-
datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/form-plugins.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/parsley/dist/parsley.js">
</script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/DataTables-
1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/DataTables-1.9.4/js/data-
table.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js">
</script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/apps.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var detalles = <?php echo json_encode($detalles); ?>;


    App.init();
    FormPlugins.init();

    //cambio el item activo en el sidebar
    $("#ULsidebar > li").removeClass("active");
    $("#LIinsumos").addClass("active");


    if(<?=$mensaje;?>== 1){
        $.gritter.add({
            title: "Exito",
            text: "Registrado con exito"
        });
    }
    if(<?=$mensaje;?>!= 1 && <?=$mensaje;?>!= 0) {
        $.gritter.add({
            title: "Exito",
            text: "Registrado con exito. Nro de Solicitud: "+<?=$mensaje;?>
        });
    }


    $("#nueva").click(function(){
        location.href="<?=base_url()?>insumos/nuevaSolicitud";
    });


    $('#data-table tbody').on('click', 'tr > td', function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('action'))
        {
            $("#solicitud").val($(this).parent().attr("id"));
            $('#modal_delete').modal('show');
        }
        else

        location.href = '<?= base_url(); ?>insumos/form/'+ $(this).parent().attr('id');                 
    });
    $('#modal_delete').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (){ $("#solicitud").val("");});



});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#formulario{  border-left: 1px solid #E4E4E4; }
</style>    
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el Data-Table.Js

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
"sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-6'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-6'i><'col-md-6 col-sm-6'p>>",
"sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
"oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ filas por página"
}
} );



/* Default class modification */
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
"sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
} );


$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
{
return {
    "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
    "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
    "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
    "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
    "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
    "iPage":          oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
        0 : Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
    "iTotalPages":    oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
        0 : Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
};
};


/* Bootstrap style pagination control */
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
"bootstrap": {
    "fnInit": function( oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw ) {
        var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
        var fnClickHandler = function ( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ( oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action) ) {
                fnDraw( oSettings );
            }
        };

        $(nPaging).addClass('pagination').append(
            '<ul class="pagination m-t-0 m-b-0">'+
                '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">&larr; '+oLang.sPrevious+'</a></li>'+
                '<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">'+oLang.sNext+' &rarr; </a></li>'+
            '</ul>'
        );
        var els = $('a', nPaging);
        $(els[0]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "previous" }, fnClickHandler );
        $(els[1]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "next" }, fnClickHandler );
    },

    "fnUpdate": function ( oSettings, fnDraw ) {
        var iListLength = 5;
        var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
        var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
        var i, ien, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf=Math.floor(iListLength/2);

        if ( oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
            iStart = 1;
            iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
        }
        else if ( oPaging.iPage <= iHalf ) {
            iStart = 1;
            iEnd = iListLength;
        } else if ( oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages-iHalf) ) {
            iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
            iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
        } else {
            iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
            iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
        }

        for ( i=0, ien=an.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
            // Remove the middle elements
            $('li:gt(0)', an[i]).filter(':not(:last)').remove();

            // Add the new list items and their event handlers
            for ( j=iStart ; j<=iEnd ; j++ ) {
                sClass = (j==oPaging.iPage+1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                $('<li '+sClass+'><a href="#">'+j+'</a></li>')
                    .insertBefore( $('li:last', an[i])[0] )
                    .bind('click', function (e) {
                        console.log((parseInt($('a', this).text(),10)));
                        e.preventDefault();
                        oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(),10)-1) * oPaging.iLength;
                        fnDraw( oSettings );
                    } );
            }

            // Add / remove disabled classes from the static elements
            if ( oPaging.iPage === 0 ) {
                $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
            } else {
                $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
            }

            if ( oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages-1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0 ) {
                $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
            } else {
                $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
            }
        }
    }
}
} );


 /*
 * TableTools Bootstrap compatibility
 * Required TableTools 2.1+
 */
 if ( $.fn.DataTable.TableTools ) {
// Set the classes that TableTools uses to something suitable for Bootstrap
$.extend( true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
    "container": "DTTT btn-group",
    "buttons": {
        "normal": "btn",
        "disabled": "disabled"
    },
    "collection": {
        "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
        "buttons": {
            "normal": "",
            "disabled": "disabled"
        }
    },
    "print": {
        "info": "DTTT_print_info modal"
    },
    "select": {
        "row": "active"
    }
} );
// Have the collection use a bootstrap compatible dropdown
$.extend( true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
    "collection": {
        "container": "ul",
        "button": "li",
        "liner": "a"
    }
} );
 }


/* Table initialisation */
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#data-table').dataTable( {
    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-6'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-6'i><'col-md-6 col-sm-6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ filas por página"
    }
});

$('#data-table2').dataTable( {
    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-6'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-6'i><'col-md-6 col-sm-6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ filas por página"
    },
    "bSort": false
});
} );
```

En esta View muestro detalles del producto

```
<link href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-
datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-
datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/parsley/src/parsley.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/DataTables-1.9.4/css/data-
table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
tr{cursor:pointer;}
@media print
{
    .panel-body{
        margin-top: -90px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }       
    .form-horizontal.form-bordered .form-group>div{
        padding: 4px !important;
    }
}
</style>

<!-- begin #content -->
<div id="content" class="content">
<?php if($data['rol'] <= 3) { ?>
<div class="panel panel-inverse no-print">              
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-inline pull-right" style="margin:0;">
                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-l-10 volver no-print" style="margin-top: -15px;">Volver</button></li>
                <li><div style="background-color: #AAA; width:1px; height: 30px;"></div></li>                   
                <li><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>insumos/imprimir/<?=$id_solicitud?>"><i class="fa fa-print fa-3x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="panel panel-inverse">
    <div class="panel-heading no-print">
        <div class="panel-heading-btn">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle 
btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle 
btn-success" data-click="panel-reload"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle 
btn-warning" data-click="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>                
        </div>
        <h4 class="panel-title">Solicitud de Formulario</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" action="<?= base_url(); 
?>insumos/ingresoUpdate" method="POST" data-parsley-validate="true">    
            <input type="hidden" name="id_solicitud" value="<?
=$id_solicitud?>">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label ui-sortable">Nº 
Solicitud</label>
                <div class="col-md-8 ui-sortable">
                    <h3 style="margin-top:0;"><?=$id_solicitud?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label ui-
sortable">Detalle</label>
                <div class="col-md-8 ui-sortable">

                <?php foreach ($detalles as $detalle): 

                    $chk = ''; 
                    if($detalle->estado == 1) 
                        $chk = 'checked'; 

                    if(isset($detalle->fecha_cierre))
                    {
                        $fechaC = new DateTime($detalle->fecha_cierre); 
                        $fechaC = date_format($fechaC,'d-m-Y');
                    }
                    else
                        $fechaC = '';

                ?>

                    <input name="id_detalle[]" type="hidden" id="id_detalle" 
value="<?=$detalle->id_insumo?>">
                    <div class="form-group m-r-10" style="margin-top: 
80px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" <?=$chk?> 
name="inputVerificado[]" value="<?=$detalle->id_insumo?>"/>
                        <label> <?=$detalle->descripcion?> | Días: <?            
=$detalle->dias?> </label>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker-
autoClose<?=$detalle->id_insumo?>" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" 
style="padding:0;">
                            <input id="inputFechaCierre" 
name="inputFechaCierre[]" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?
=$fechaC?>" placeholder="Fecha Ciere Pedido" /><span class="input-group-
addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>      
                        <br>                    
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Comentario" 
class="form-control" name="inputComentario[]" id="inputComentario" value="<?
=$detalle->comentarios?>" />
                    </div>

                <?php endforeach; ?>    


                </div>


                <div class="form-group no-print" style="display:none">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label ui-sortable">Cerrar 
Formulario</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8 ui-sortable">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cerrarF" name="cerrarF">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>




            <div class="form-group no-print">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label ui-sortable"></label>
                <div class="col-md-8 ui-sortable">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-r-5">Guardar</button>                             
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-l-10 volver">Volver</button>              
                    <button type="button" id="btnCerrar" class="btn btn-sm btn-default m-l-10">Cerrar</button>              
                </div>
            </div>      
        </form>
    </div>
</div>  

<?php } ?>  


</div>

<?php $this->load->view('view_scripts') ?>

<!-- ================== BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JS ================== -->
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-
datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/form-plugins.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/parsley/dist/parsley.js">
</script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/DataTables-
1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/DataTables-1.9.4/js/data-
table.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/apps.min.js"></script>
<!-- ================== END PAGE LEVEL JS ================== -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


    App.init();
    FormPlugins.init();
    //cambio el item activo en el sidebar
    $("#ULsidebar > li").removeClass("active");
    $("#LIinsumos").addClass("active");




    $('.volver').click(function () {
        console.log((parseInt($('a', this).text(),10)));
        location.href = '<?= base_url(); ?>insumos';
    });

    $("#LIinsumos").addClass("active");

    if('<?=$estado_solicitud?>' == '2')
    {
        $('#cerrarF').prop('checked', true);

        $("#inputFechaOrden").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#btnGuardar").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#btnCerrar").prop('disabled', true);

        $("checkbox").each(function(){
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        });
        $("input").each(function(){
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        });



        $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("NO SE PUEDE EDITAR");
        });

    }

    $("#btnCerrar").click(function(){
        $("#cerrarF").prop('checked', true);
        var enviar = true;

        /*$("textarea").each(function(){
            if(this.value=='')
            {
                alert("Debe completar todos los campos");
                enviar = false;
            }               
        });*/

        if(enviar == true)
        {
            $("form").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow, deberías agregar el código que has tratado de utilizar y decir específicamente que fue lo que no te funcionó, te invito a que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Muchas gracias @CamiloVasquez! Voy a ingresar a ese link para leer como hacer las preguntas y voy a subir el codigo!

Comment: Ahi subi el codigo, asi estaria bien formulada la pregunta @CamiloVasquez?

Comment: No es necesario que subas todo el código, basta con publicar el/los fragmentos de código que tienen que ver directamente con el problema, pero esta bien :D avísame si te funciona la respuesta que te he dado !

Comment: Genial @CamiloVasquez estoy probando. En mi caso la variable table = $('#data-table').DataTable()? Perdon pero soy durisimo con esto! Gracias!

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta !

Comment: Me refiero a que no estoy entendiendo de donde sale la variable **table**. En este caso **$('#example').DataTable()** a que seria igual? (#example)??
@CamiloVasquez

Comment: Ah claro, #example hace referencia a la tabla data-table, aunque revisando tu código no veo no encuentro donde estás haciendo el .DataTable()

Answer (score 3):

Para la solución a tu problema yo haría algo como esto, espero que te funcione, con gusto resuelvo las dudas que tengas:

En la función donde das `click` al botón de detalle simplemente capturaría la página actual y la guardaría usando el `localstorage` del navegador:

```
//Función para ver el detalle
$("#verdetalle").click(function(){
    //Capturas página actual
    var pagina_actual = table.page();

    //Guardamos la página actual en el local storage
    localStorage.setItem("pagina_actual", pagina_actual);
});
```

Después en la función donde generas la tabla capturaría el valor guardado, preguntaría si existe y en caso tal de que exista daría la orden a la tabla de mostrar dicha página. (Esto tiene que ser obviamente después de imprimir todos los datos nuevamente de la tabla)

```
//capturamos la página guardada anteriormente
var pagina = localStorage.getItem("pagina_actual");

// Pregutnamos si existe el item
if (pagina != undefined) {
    //Decimos a la table que cargue la página requerida
    table.page(pagina).draw('page');;

    //Eliminamos el item para que no genere conflicto a la hora de dar click en otro botón detalle
    localStorage.removeItem("pagina_actual");
}
```

Vale aclarar que `table` es la variable donde guardas la línea `$('#example').DataTable();`

**Otra solución podría ser mostrar el detalle en una modal**

Answer (score 3):

Si he entendido bien la pregunta, la solución es la siguiente:

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
stateSave: true,
...
})
```

stateSave guarda la vista de la tabla tal y como la dejaste la última vez que visitaste la página. Puedes hacer F5 salir de la vista, volver a entrar, etc... y la tabla se te mostrará igual.